# Should the Presenter know about the Activity in Android MVP architecture?

Tags: java, android

I am wondering if the `Activity` should be referenced or not within `Presenter` code when using the Android MVP architecture?

The example MVP architecture that I have found so far doesn't reference it, but in my code it's not a property on the Presenter, but an argument in some methods.  Could this lead to issues?  Does this not follow Android MVP?

Here is a code example from one Presenter:

```
package com.example.example;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

import com.example.example.util.Constants;
import com.example.example.util.ImageFile;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Presenter from home screen, (Main), of the app
 */
public class MainPresenter implements MainContract.Presenter {

    private final MainContract.View mView;
    private final ImageFile mImageFile;

    public MainPresenter(MainContract.View mainView, ImageFile imageFile) {
        mView = mainView;
        mImageFile = imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void takePicture(FragmentActivity activity) throws IOException {
        mImageFile.create(activity);

        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                activity,
                Constants.FILE_PROVIDER_PATH,
                mImageFile.getFile());

        mView.openCamera(photoUri);
    }

    Uri getImageFileUri() {
        return  mImageFile.getUri();
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you just add a few parameters to openCamera() so that you don't need the activity inside the presenter? the way you're doing it now it's creating an android dependency to your presenter which is something you would like to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In proper MVP implementation, Presenter should not know about the activity. If we'll use activity then we'll have to mock the activity during testing, that'll make the testing difficult. So, in your case, you should pass your mImageFile to activity through the view reference and create the URI inside activity class.